# C: strings and pointers. changing sub-strings within a string in a specific pattern

Tags: c, string, parsing

I'm having a hard time understanding how should I do the following:

I have a list of words defined like so:

```
typedef struct _StringNode {
  char *str;
  struct _StringNode* next;
} StringNode;
```

Now I need to write a function which receives a string, and two word lists of the same length, and I need to replace every appearance of a word from the first list in the string with the corresponding word from the second list.

Example:

```
        text: "stack overflow siteoverflow oveflow stack"
    patterns: [ "stack", "overflow", "site" ]
replacements: [ "Hello", "guys", "here" ]
      result: "Hello guys hereguys guys Hello"
```

For each word: I'm trying to use `strstr()` so I'll get a pointer to an occurrence of the word in a copy of the string and then to change the word, and to promote the pointer of the copy of the text string.

```
char* replace(const char *text,
              const StringNode *patterns,
              const StringNode *replacements);
```

Comment: each node has one words, and the two lists contains the same number of  nodes. I deleted the code, I had a feeling that it is not correct.

Comment: Side note, don't use names that start with `_` followed by a capital letter. They are [reserved](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html). In C, you can safely write `typedef struct StringNode { ... } StringNode;`

Comment: I added a Python-style syntax to the lists and quoted the strings, to make it more clear.

Comment: Do you expect to replace any matches of the pattern in the text, or *only* words (i.e. match surrounded by whitespace)?

Comment: And what if [ "a", "a" ] => [ "b", "c" ] or, what is much worse [ "a", "b" ] => [ "b", "a" ]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
char *strnreplace(char *st,const int length, 
                  const char *orig,const char *repl) {

  static char buffer[length];
  char *ch;

  if (!(ch = strstr(st, orig)))
      return st;

  strncpy(buffer, st, ch-st);
  buffer[ch-st] = 0;
  sprintf(buffer+(ch-st), "%s%s", repl, ch+strlen(orig));
  return buffer;
}


void replace(const char *text,
              const StringNode *patterns,
              const StringNode *replacements)
{
  StringNode *pat, *rep;
  char *temp = text;
  int length = strlen(text);
  for( pat = patterns, rep = replacements;
        pat->next != NULL;
        pat = pat->next, rep = rep->next ) {
        temp = strnreplace(temp, length, pat->str, rep->str);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
char* replace(const char *text,
              const StringNode *patterns,
              const StringNode *replacements)
{
  char *out = malloc(1024), *put = out;

  while(*text != '\0)
  {
    const StringNode *piter, *riter;
    int found = 0;

    /* Check if current start of text matches any pattern. */
    for(piter = patterns, riter = replacements;
        piter != NULL;
        piter = piter->next, riter = riter->next)
    {
      const size_t plen = strlen(piter->str);
      if(strncmp(text, piter->str, plen) == 0)
      {
        /* Hit found, emit replacement. */
        const size_t rlen = strlen(riter->str);
        memcpy(out, riter->str, rlen);
        out += rlen;
        text += plen;
        found = 1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(!found)
      *put++ = *text++;
  }
  *put = '\0';

  return out;
}
```

Note that the above does *not* handle buffer overflows, omitted for brevity. I would recommend implementing something like this on top of a dynamic string data type, to make the core operation (append) automatically grow the destination string as needed.

**UPDATE** In response to the comment, the algorithm the above is trying to implement is:

```
set output to empty string
while text remaining
  if start of text matches pattern[i]
    append replacement[i] to output
    remove len(pattern[i]) characters from start of text
  else
    append first character of text to output
    remove first character of text
```

So, it *repeatedly* checks for pattern-matches, as long as there is anything left in `text`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it looks like that whenever you find a sub string which matches piter->str you change it and go on to the next word, but what if there are more words piter->str sub-strings in text?

Comment: @Numerator I added an outline of the algorithm, hopefully it helps you understand it. In short, it checks for pattern matches for every single character of `text`, so it will find any later matches when it comes to them.

Comment: Thank you very much @unwind. Very helpful. I'll work on it :)